# Баги powershell

Tags: powershell

Натолкнулся на баг в 3-й и 4-й версии powershell-а (во 2-й версии все работает)

```
$newvar=if (0) {55}; switch($newvar) { "r"{1}; default{2}}
```

Добавление else делает код работоспособным (на версии 3,4)

```
$newvar=if (0) {55} else {$null}; switch($newvar) { "r"{1}; default{2}}
```

В укороченном виде  `switch($(if (0) {55})) { default{2}}`
не работает ни на какой версии.
Но если else добавить то заработает везде:

```
switch($(if (0) {55} else {$null})) { default{2}}
```

Может кто-нибудь сказать, где найти полный список багов/фич powershell-а?

Answer (score 5):

Честно говоря, для меня это ожидаемое поведение. Если команда записала в выходной поток нуль элементов, то результат выполнения команды не `$null`, а `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`. Это особое значение воспринимается как пустое множество, а не как одно значение `$null`. Цикл по пустом множеству (а `switch` в PowerShell — это именно цикл) даст нуль итераций, что собственно Вы и наблюдаете. А в PowerShell v2 есть бага/фича: при сохранении `AutomationNull` в переменную, `AutomationNull` преобразуется в обычный `$null`.

Насчёт списка багов, официальный источник — это [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Однако с интерпретацией несогласен. Конструкция `switch($anyvalue) { default {1} }` должна в любом случае выдать либо exception либо 1. Если данная конструкция этого не делает, то это никакая не фича, а просто баг. Собственно switch работает правильно (Даже с заведомо неиспользуемой ранее переменной), если перед ним нет присвоения результата if без else. Кроме того если значение переменной после обрезанного if становится `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` то почему if с ней работает нормально `$any= if (0){1}; if ($any -eq $null ) {1}`
,преобразов

Comment: Повторю сказанное PetSerAl: `switch` - это оператор цикла. В том числе с точки зрения программиста. Гляньте хотя бы https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx, раздел "Using Arrays with the Switch Statement"

Comment: Спасибо. Так понятней. Действительно Вы правы.Я ответ невнимательно прочел.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут отличная подборка странностей в PowerShell:

- https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShellTraps

> PowerShellTraps is a collection of some PowerShell traps and oddities shown by demo scripts with workarounds and automated tests.